# An entropy inequality

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, inequalities, it.information-theory, entropy

> Let $X,Y$ be probability measures on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and set $K=\sum_i\sqrt{X(i)Y(i)}$ so that $Z:=\frac{1}{K}\sqrt{XY}$ is also a probability measure on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  How can we prove the inequality
> $$H(X)+H(Y)\geq 2K^2 H(Z),$$ where $H(X)=-\sum_{i=1}^n X(i)\log X(i)$ is the [entropy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29).

The problem originates from this [math stack exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41340/im-not-sure-about-this-inequality-how-to-prove-or-disprove-it), and [cardinal's rewording](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41340/im-not-sure-about-this-inequality-how-to-prove-or-disprove-it#comment92485_41340) of it in the comments.  Despite having being asked over two years ago, with numerous bounties posted, the problem was never solved, and for that reason I am posting it here.

I checked the inequality numerically on matlab for millions of choices of $X$ and $Y$, with $n$ up to size $100$, and it always held, which suggests that finding a counter example is unlikely.

**Remark:** By Cauchy Schwarz, $1\geq K^2,$ so the above inequality would be implied by $H(X)+H(Y)\geq 2H(Z).$  However it is worth noting that this inequality does not hold, so the factor of $K^2$ is important.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for reminding me of this question. I played with it pretty intensely for a couple of afternoons when it was first posted, but it seemed quite tight, and then I had to move on to other things and it faded from memory. Seeing a solution would be nice.

Comment: It is likely I am simply misreading it, but I think the $\mathbb E$ should be replaced by sums everywhere it occurs.

Comment: @cardinal: Thank you, corrected.  I wrote things incorrectly.

Comment: Looks like you can do it entry-wise if you take into account that $\sqrt{X_jY_j}\le K\le\sqrt{X_jY_j}+\sqrt{(1-X_j)(1-Y_j)}$ for every $j$. I'll see if I can pull it through.

Comment: I believe I have reduced it to $x,y,z>0,xy=z^2\Longrightarrow (1+x)\log(1+y)+(1+y)\log(1+x)\ge 2(1+z)\log(1+z)$. Still have no elegant proof of that one (I prefer to avoid brute force differentiation unless completely cornered). Any ideas?

Comment: fedja, isn't this just convexity of the function $(1+e^x)\log(1+e^x)$ (which is easy)?

Comment: You, probably, meant "convexity of the function $(1+ze^x)\log(1+ze^{-x})$, (which fails for some $z>0$)". ;)

Comment: right :-------)

Comment: But the function $(1+ze^x)\log(1+ze^{-x}) + (1+ze^{-x})\log(1+ze^{x})$ is convex, which yields the desired inequality (proving this without the "monster style" seems to be not easy...)

Comment: It is not in general . Check your computations.

Comment: ok, indeed, as $z$ grows larger, it becomes trivial to find a counterexample....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, having spent about 20 hours on the search of a nice proof (which extinguished my passion for beauty for the next several days at least), I'm resorting to the brute force. I will love to see someone else to avenge this pitiful defeat of mine...

As I mentioned in the comment, the key to the solution is the inequality
$$
(1+a)\log(1+b)+(1+b)\log(1+a)\ge 2(1+c)\log(1+c)
$$
where $a,b,c>0, ab=c^2$.
Consider the function
$$
F(t)=(1+a)\log(1+bt)+(1+b)\log(1+at)-2(1+c)\log(1+ct)\,.
$$
We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
F'(t)&=\frac{(1+a)b}{1+bt}+\frac{(1+b)a}{1+at}-2\frac{(1+c)c}{1+ct}
\\
&=(a+b-2c)\frac{(c^2t-1)(ct-1)}{(1+at)(1+bt)(1+ct)}
\end{aligned}
$$
While the derivation of the last equality is tedious, to check it, it suffices to show that $F'(c^{-2})=F'(c^{-1})=0$ and to compute the free term in the numerator to get the right normalization factor, so I'll skip the explicit computations.
It will be convenient to denote $p=c^{-1}$. Then we need to show that
$$
\int_0^1\frac{(t-p^2)(t-p)}{(1+at)(1+bt)(1+ct)}\,dt\ge 0\,.
$$ 
If $p>1$, there is nothing to do because the integrand is non-negative. So, we'll assume that $p<1$ from now on.
Since the denominator is increasing in $t$, and the numerator is positive on $(0,p^2)$, negative on $(p^2,p)$ and then positive again on $(p,1)$, we would be in good shape if we had
$$
\int_0^p(t-p^2)(t-p)\,dt=-\frac{p^3}6+\frac{p^4}2\ge 0\,,
$$
which is true for $p\ge \frac 13$. Thus, we may assume that $p<\frac 13$.

Now we cannot just neglect the interval $[p,1]$. We shall neglect the interval $[0,p^2]$ instead. Assuming $a\ge c\ge b$, we write 
$$
\begin{multline}
\int_{p^2}^p\frac{(t-p^2)(t-p)}{(1+at)(1+bt)(1+ct)}\,dt=
\int_p^1\frac{(t-p)(t-1)p^2}{(p^{-1}+at)(1+bpt)(1+cpt)}\,dt
\\
\ge
\int_p^1\frac{(t-p)(t-1)p^2}{(1+at)(1+bpt)(1+t)}\,dt
\end{multline}
$$
Combining this with $\int_p^1$, we get the lower bound
$$
\int_p^1\frac{(t-p)}{(1+at)}\left[\frac{(t-1)p^2}{(1+bpt)(1+t)}
+\frac{t-p^2}{(1+bt)(1+ct)}\right]\,dt
$$
Note now that $bp\le 1$ and the higher $b$ is, the harder it is for the last square bracket to be non-negative. Thus, it is enough to estimate the bracket for $bp=1$, i.e., to demonstrate that
$$
(1-t)(p+t)^2\le (t-p^2)(1+t)^2\,.
$$
However
$$
t-p^2\ge t(1-t)
$$
and
$$
(p+t)^2=2pt+p^2+t^2<t+2t^2<t(1+t)^2\,.
$$
I would appreciate it if someone checks this ugly monster before I post the remaining (almost trivial) part of the proof :).

Edit: Assuming that those who upvoted took trouble to read and verify the above part, the end is as follows.

Let $X=X_j$, $Y=Y_j$, and $K$ be as before. Then, as I said, $\sqrt{XY}\le K\le\sqrt{XY}+\sqrt{(1-X)(1-Y)}$ (Cauchy). We have $Z=Z_j=\frac{\sqrt{XY}}K$, so it will suffice to show that
$$
2K^2 Z\log\frac 1Z=2K\sqrt{XY}\log\frac{K}{\sqrt{XY}}\le X\log\frac 1X+Y\log\frac 1Y\,.
$$
Note that the left hand side is convex in $K$ for fixed $X,Y$. If $K=\sqrt{XY}$, the inequality is trivial ($0$ is less than or equal to a non-negative number). Thus, we need only consider the case $K=\sqrt{XY}+\sqrt{(1-X)(1-Y)}$. Dividing by $XY$ and putting $X^{-1}=1+x, Y^{-1}=1+y$, so that $\frac{1-X}X=x,\frac{1-Y}Y=y$, we see that this case reduces exactly to the above inequality.

P.S. There is an [alternative proof](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=547118) of the main inequality on AoPS. Alas, it also requires some tedious computations...

Comment: The connection is just terrible and rendering LaTeX in the process makes the browser stop, cursor jump, etc. I'll try to finish but each line is a fight :(.

Comment: I'm confused; in the bit after "Assuming $a\ge c\ge b$", the inequality seems the wrong way round.  Because $p^{-1}>1$ so $(p^{-1}+at)^{-1} < (1+at)^{-1}$, right?

Comment: Of course. But it is a factor in the *negative* part!

Comment: Oh, silly me!  By the way, you should maybe post this as an answer on the original Math.SE post as well.

Comment: Maybe, but I have spent enough time on this already. It was Eric, who asked the question, so it is his job to link everything now :).

Comment: @fedja Thank you for sharing your answer.  I posted a link to this page on [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/472472/6075).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative proof of 
the inequality
$$
(1+a)\ln(1+b)+(1+b)\ln(1+a)\ge 2(1+c)\ln(1+c) \tag{1}
$$
with 
$$a,b,c>0,\ ab=c^2,\tag{2}$$
proved in the above answer.

The left-hand side of $(1)$ goes to $\infty$ as $a$ or $b$ does so while keeping condition $(2)$. So, it remains to show that a  conditional local extremum given $(2)$ can only be attained when $a=b$ and hence $a=b=c$. 
Without loss of generality, $a<b$. 
By Lagrange multipliers, for any such local extremum $(a,b)$ one has 
$\ln(1+b)+\frac{1+b}{1+a}=\lambda b$ and $\ln(1+a)+\frac{1+a}{1+b}=\lambda a$ for some real $\lambda$. Multiplying these two equations by $a$ and $b$, respectively, and then subtracting one from the other, for
$$d(a,b):=a\ln(1+b)+a\,\frac{1+b}{1+a}-b\ln(1+a)-b\,\frac{1+a}{1+b}
$$
one has $d(a,b)=0$ if $(a,b)$ is a local extremum. But $d''_{b,a}(a,b)=\frac b{1 + b^2}- \frac a{1 + a^2}$, which vanishes only if $a=b$ or $ab=1$. 
Next, 
$$d'_b(a,b)=\frac{a^2 b+a b (b+3)-1}{(1+a) (1+b)^2}-\ln(1+a). 
$$
So, $d'_b(0+,b)=-1/(1+b)^2<0$, $d'_b(1/b,b)\big|_{b=1/a}=\frac a{1+a}-\ln(1+a)<0$, and $d'_b(b,b)=\frac{2b-1}{1+b}-\ln(1+b)<0$ (the latter two inequalities easily checked by differentiation). 
So, $d'_b(a,b)<0$ whenever $0<a<b$. 
So, $d(a,b)<d(a,a)=0$ whenever $0<a<b$, which contradicts the necessary condition $d(a,b)=0$ for $(a,b)$ to be a  conditional local extremum. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

*Remark*: This is to give an alternative proof of the inequality in fedja's nice [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138275/an-entropy-inequality/139166#139166):
$$
(1+a)\log(1+b)+(1+b)\log(1+a)\ge 2(1+c)\log(1+c)
$$
where $a, b, c>0$ with $ab=c^2$.

**Proof**.

WLOG, assume that $a \le b$.
Let $x = \frac{a}{c} \in (0, 1]$.
It suffices to prove that
$$f(x) := (1 + cx)\ln(1 + c/x) + (1 + c/x)\ln(1 + cx) - 2(1 + c)\ln(1 + c) \ge 0.$$

We have
$$f'(x) = c\ln(1 + c/x) - \frac{c(1+cx)}{x(x + c)}
- \frac{c\ln(1 + cx)}{x^2} + \frac{c(x+c)}{x(1+cx)}$$
and
$$f''(x) = \frac{2c}{x^2(x+c)} - \frac{c^2(1+cx)}{x^2(x+c)^2} + \frac{2c\ln(1+cx)}{x^3} - \frac{2c^2}{x^2(1+cx)} - \frac{c^2(x+c)}{x(1+cx)^2}.$$

Let $g(x) := x^3 f''(x)$. We have
\begin{align*}
    g'(x) &= \frac{c^2(1-x^2)}{(x+c)^3(1+cx)^3}\\
    &\qquad \times [cx^4 + (c^2 + 3)x^3 + (2c^5 - 6c^3 + 10c)x^2 + (c^2 + 3)x + c]\\
    & \ge 0.
\end{align*}
Also, $g(0) = 0$. Thus, $g(x) \ge 0$ on $(0, 1]$. Thus, $f''(x) \ge 0$ on $(0, 1]$. Also, $f'(1) = 0$. Thus, $f'(x) \le 0$ on $(0, 1]$.
Also, $f(1) = 0$. Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ on $(0, 1]$.

We are done.